# Use IdentityServer for Angular but also with EF client store

Tags: asp.net-core, identityserver4

I am trying to get my IdentityServer based ASP.NET Core application to work for an Angular web client, but also for other clients that are configured via an Entity Framework client store.

For the Angular client, I use AddApiAuthorization() / AddIdentityServerJwt() and this works properly.

For the EF client store, I use AddConfigurationStore().

The problem now is, that only one of both is working - if I call AddConfigurationStore() after AddApiAuthorization(), then the EF clients work. If I call AddApiAuthorization() after AddConfigurationStore(), then the Angular client works but not the EF clients.

I have debugged into AddApiAuthorization() and it adds its clients from the configuration file and therefore simply ignores the EF based client store.

Is there a way to combine both to a working solution?